# React js material ui textfield to be able to tag users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, chat, textfield

[image]
I should do a similar thing on `React js`, as is the possibility of being able to tag users in `chat`.

The problem is that the `textfield` must be able to allow both to insert normal text and to be able to tag various `users`, as seen in the photo.

How can I do using material ui?

Only thing I could find is this: [multiple-values](https://v4-10-2.material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values)

But it only allows you to select users in case.

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: It's not  possible to do it in textarea. You should use contenteditable element. draw-js can be helpful

Comment: Why it is not possible? The first idead is to track what you write into input, if inside message you have @ mark then show list component with users and while writing name after @ than just filter a list. When selected some person from the list just wrap the name into span which will be colored as you wish and put into texarea and so on.. Just try not to rely only on provided components, try to think by yourself or find already created npm package.